# CSS Display InfoBox on hovering over <span> Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, styled-components

I want to implement a functionality in my React app where you hover over a `<span>` element and then an *InfoBox* appears over the `<span>` element.

It should look like in Visual Studio code when you hover your cursor over a variable for example.
[image: VSCode on hover]

The box should behave as in the following sketch I drew (basically it's the same behavior as in VSCode): The InfoBox is the box that contains **This text**. The `<span>` contains the **hello**

[image: Sketch how the infoBox should behave]

Unfortunately I'm not an expert in CSS and I don't even know if this is possible with CSS only or if you have to use javascript as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into similar things so figured I might share what I ended up with.

If you go to `Help > Toggle Developer Tools` it opens up the Dev Tools just like in Chrome on the side. Seems like most Electron based apps have this (although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>—I'm on Windows—didn't work for me on VS Code somehow. Needed to open it via mouse through the aforementioned method).

With the Dev Tools you can then view what HTML, JavaScript, and CSS is used to make the displayed UI possible. I opened up the console tab at the bottom so that I can type on it while I use my mouse to hover on things, then I entered `debugger` command in the console to pause the JS execution or something (don't quote me on this). Point is it pauses the state of everything so you can then keep the tooltip that is created with JavaScript in display.

Seems like it's just standard Tooltip positioning with `display: block` and `position: fixed`, as well as `max-width`, `top` and `left` set by calculated JavaScript. There's also a `z-index` rule set by a class selector but that's on the stylesheet.

```css
element.style {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    visibility: inherit;
    max-width: 1152px;
    top: 85px;
    left: 147px;
}
```

Personally I would use `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`. I would guess they used `fixed` in Visual Studio Code instead because of the way they calculated the position inside each "split view" (the windows), because the overridden CSS stylesheet did use `position: absolute` as seen here.

```css
.monaco-hover {
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
    user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    box-sizing: initial;
    animation: fadein .1s linear;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

I recognize this doesn't fully answer the question (nothing on how to get or set the dimensions) but I know where I need to go myself from here on, and for those answers I think you can go looking for answers elsewhere depending on if you're writing vanilla JS, or using some framework (in which case there might be an easier way to get, calculate, and set those things).

Comment: Hey, this is a great idea you had there! I fixed my css already but I will keep this trick in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Where you hover over some text and text below it appears?

```css
.thisText > .hello {
  display: none;
}

.thisText:hover > .hello {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="thisText">
This Text
  <span class="hello">
    Hello
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The InfoBox should appear on top of the `hello` element.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
.thisText{
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
 }

.thisText > .hello{
  display: none;
}

.thisText:hover> .hello {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
}

<span class="thisText">
This Text
  <span class="hello">
    Hello
  </span>
</span>
```